# Galería de imágenes más carrousel

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas quiero hacer una galería en la que sale una foto principal y unas miniaturas abajo, y según hagas clic en una de las de abajo, se carga en la parte superior. He encontrado un desarrollo en google que es lo que quiero pero no lo hago funcionar.

**Código HTML**

```
<div id="content">
  <img id="bigimage" src="{{ asset("{$producto->foto}") }}"/>
   <div id="carrusel">
     <a href="#" class="izquierda_flecha"><img src="{{ asset('images/flecha_01.png')}}" /></a>
     <a href="#" class="derecha_flecha"><img src="{{ asset('images/flecha_02.png')}}" /></a>
   <div class="carrusel">
      @php $contador=0; @endphp;
      @foreach ($producto->galerias as $item)
        <div id="imagen_{{$contador}}"><img class="img_carrusel" src="{{ asset("{$item->foto}") }}" width="195px" height="100px" /></div> 
         @php $contador= $contador + 1 @endphp;
      @endforeach
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    var posicion = 0;
    var imagenes = new Array();
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var numeroImatges = 4;
      if(numeroImatges<=3){
          $('.derecha_flecha').css('display','none');
          $('.izquierda_flecha').css('display','none');
      }
   
        $('.img_carrusel').live('click',function(){
            $('#bigimage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
           return false;
        });
   
        $('.izquierda_flecha').live('click',function(){
            if(posicion>0){
               posicion = posicion-1;
           }else{
               posicion = numeroImatges-3;
           }
           $(".carrusel").animate({"left": -($('#imagen_'+posicion).position().left)}, 600);
           return false;
        });
   
        $('.izquierda_flecha').hover(function(){
            $(this).css('opacity','0.5');
        },function(){
            $(this).css('opacity','1');
        });
   
        $('.derecha_flecha').hover(function(){
            $(this).css('opacity','0.5');
        },function(){
            $(this).css('opacity','1');
        });
   
        $('.derecha_flecha').live('click',function(){
           if(numeroImatges>posicion+3){
               posicion = posicion+1;
           }else{
               posicion = 0;
           }
           $(".carrusel").animate({"left": -($('#imagen_'+posicion).position().left)}, 600);
           return false;
        });
   
    });
```

Pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
```

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser con jQuery? El error, seguramente, se debe a que estás cargando jQuery, pero no el _script_ del slider.

Comment: Hola @Triby que tal, probe ahora en lugar de poner `$('.img_carrusel').live('click',function(){` puse el metodo on `$('.izquierda_flecha').on('click',function(){`

Comment: Lo malo es que no se como hacer que detecte el numero de imagenes automaticamente en lugar de poner `var numeroImatges = 4;`

Comment: [`live()`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) es obsoleto, en su lugar, deberías usar `on()`, solo remplaza la función y listo.

Comment: Y como hago que detecte el total de imagenes para sustituir el `var numeroImatges = 4`

Comment: Prueba con `var numeroImatges = $('.img_carousel').length;`

Comment: No solo me carga tres de este modo @Triby

Comment: Nada no he dicho nada, era con dos `rr` `.img_carousel` funciona perfecto, publica si quieres la solución y la marco